# Why does bob instanceof Person return false?

Tags: javascript, class

I need someone to explain to me why `bob instanceof Person` returns false from this code:

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {

    var names = firstAndLast.split(' ');

    return {

        getFirstName:  function() {
          return names[0];
        },

        getLastName: function() {
          return names[1];
        },

        getFullName: function() {
          return names[0] + " " + names[1];
        },

        setFirstName: function(first) {
          names[0] = first;
        },

        setLastName: function(last) {
          names[1] = last;
        },

        setFullName: function(firstAndLast) {
          names = firstAndLast.split(' ');
        }

    };  

};

var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');
```

I've tried looking for an answer but I couldn't find anything. As far as I understand `bob instanceof Person` should return true but it doesn't.

Comment: Not a constructor without `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning an object from the constructor. That object is not the object that was initialized by `new`, so it's not an instance of the `Person` class. You should be assigning to `this.propertyname` in the constructor, and let it return its default value.

```js
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {

  var names = firstAndLast.split(' ');


  this.getFirstName = function() {
    return names[0];
  };

  this.getLastName = function() {
    return names[1];
  };

  this.getFullName = function() {
    return names[0] + " " + names[1];
  };

  this.setFirstName = function(first) {
    names[0] = first;
  };

  this.setLastName = function(last) {
    names[1] = last;
  };

  this.setFullName = function(firstAndLast) {
    names = firstAndLast.split(' ');
  };

};

var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');

console.log(bob instanceof Person);
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense